# api.ai - Getting forbidden for GET /INTENTS query -

Tags: android, http, android-intent, get, dialogflow-es

I am trying to get the 'user says' list in the intents.
I hit the road block - when the following command doesn't work - says forbidden.
curl 'https://api.api.ai/v1/intents?v=20150910' -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx'

How do I frame the get request to get the 'user says' for each intent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exactly this is the correct answer - We need to send Developer access token
not client access token

Answer (score 2):

It seems you used the wrong access token. To get `intents` information from [api.ai](https://api.ai/), you need to use **"Developer access token"**, not "Client access token". According to the [document](https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/):

> There are two access tokens for each agent. The developer access token is used for managing entities and intents, and the client access token is used for making queries.

If "client access token" is used to fetch `intents`, api.ai will return `403 forbidden` error:

```
{"status":{"code":403,"errorType":"forbidden","errorDetails":"You do not have rights for this operation."}}
```

Moreover, if "user says" list is needed, the HTTP request URL should include intent id, such as:

```
curl -k -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_DEVELOPER_ACCESS_TOKEN' 'https://api.api.ai/v1/intents/<INTENT_ID>?v=20150910'
```

Comment: @MattJerry Please refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."